# Difference between running and executing states of a process in the Operating System

Tags: process, operating-system, computer-science, multitasking

I'm confused between two similar terms, *`running`* and *`executing`*.

*So, I appreciate you if you explains:*

- What is the difference between `running` and `executing` states of a
  process in the Operating System?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Running` a program means **loading program binary** image **from secondary storage to main memory**.

When program run first time it's process control block created(PCB) and exist until program terminated. A program in running state called a process.

`Execution` of program means it's **running and consume CPU cycle**.